# Hessian in spherical coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

consider a function $f$ such that for some other function $g$
$$(\nabla f)(x)= g(\Vert x \Vert) \frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert}.$$

So the gradient of this function is a vector that depends only on the radius.

Is there a simple way to compute the Hessian of the function $f$ using that $\nabla f$ 
depends only on one coordinate anymore, essentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hessian reduces down nicely. Taking the partial derivative:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(g(||x||)\frac{x_i}{||x||}\right) = g'(||x||)\frac{x_i x_j}{||x||^2} + g(||x||)\left( \frac{\delta_{ij}}{||x||} - \frac{x_i x_j}{||x||^3} \right)$$

$$\implies \mathbf{H} = \left(\frac{g(||x||)}{||x||}\right)\mathbf{I} + \left(\frac{||x||g'(||x||)-g(||x||)}{||x||^3}\right)\mathbf{x}\otimes \mathbf{x}$$